# Diagonal line in Fitted vs Residuals graph?

Tags: r, subset, linear-regression, modeling

I have a data set of terrorist incidents in the world (from Global Terrorism Database). I have built a liner model, below, and have plotted the fitted versus residuals but I get a prominent diagonal line in my graph. Why? How to remove it?

```
lmods<-lm(Iraq.incidents~Afghanistan.incidents+Pakistan.incidents+France.incidents+`United Kingdom.incidents`+`United States.incidents`+Germany.incidents, singular.ok = FALSE, country_list3.func)
```

Residual vs fitted graph:
[image: Residual vs fitted graph]

Comment: Yes this database is public - Global terrorism Database. I use the $\tilde$ as Iraq is my response and Afghan is my explanatory variable.